# Take every second element from list of lists and square it in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to get something like this:
[[1,2,3,4],[2,3],[4,5,6,7],[1,2]]=[4,16,9,25,49,4]

First i tried to write function that prints every second element.
I still have to square the results.

```
   takeSecond :: [a] -> [a]
    takeSecond [] = []
    takeSecond [a] = []
    takeSecond (y:x:xs) = [x] ++ takeSecond xs
    
    fun :: [[a]] -> [a]
    fun [] = []
    fun (x:xs) = (takeSecond x) ++ (fun xs)
```

I have accomplished:

[[1,2,3,4],[2,3],[4,5,6,7],[1,2]]=[2,4,3,5,7,2]

Comment: Should an input of `[[1],[2,3]]` result in an output of `[4]` or `[9]`?

Comment: result should be [9]

Answer (score 2):

You only need to square `x`, so:

```
takeSecondSquared :: Num a => [a] -> [a]
takeSecondSquared (_:x:xs) = x*x : takeSecond xs
takeSecondSquared _ = []
```

and use that in the `fun` to concatenate the results.

You need to add a `Num a =>` type constraint, since only for numerical types, one can multiply an two values.

Another option is to square the items that are produced by the `takeSecond` function:

```
fun :: [[a]] -> [a]
fun [] = []
fun (x:xs) = map (\x -> x * x) takeSecond x ++ fun xs
```

Comment: It is possible to do this in one function?

Comment: @Sooco: you use two functions `fun` and `takeSecond`...

Comment: @Sooco: while possible, it would look like bad code design.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do it with one function:

```
foo :: (Num a) => [[a]] -> [a]
foo ((_:b:c):xs) = b*b : foo ((b:c):xs)
foo (_:xs) = foo xs
foo _ = []
```

This code contains an intentional error, which should be easy to fix after you've understood it.

Comment: I think by "every second element", the asker meant "every other element", not "the second element".

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica ah, indeed, looks like it. :) will delete.

Comment: I've made a complete re-edit.